# ansible: get list of subelements and assert for duplicates

Tags: python, testing, ansible, infrastructure

Given a dictionary, assert for duplicates in the same list.

`vars.yml` file :

```
---
customer_domains:
  - name: myBank.org
  - name: myBakery.net
  - name: mySchool.edu
    smtp_username: smtp-school
    sender_domains:
      - sender1.tld
  - name: myRestaurant.net
  - name: myHouse.org
    smtp_relay_host: smtp-house.org
    smtp_relay_port: 25
    sender_domains:
      - test1.com
      - test1.com
      - test2.net
      - test3.house.net
```

What we really want is to make sure we don't have duplicate sender_domains for every *name*.
Same sender_domains but in different *name*s are allowed.

Doing a bit o research I was able to create the following task, which shows the value of sender_domains in every execution. However, what we really want is a list of all sender_domains from every *name* so we can assert for duplicates afterwards.

```
- name: DEBUG VAR=ITEM.1
  debug: var=item.1
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ customer_domains }}"
    - sender_domains
```

Thoughts?

This works to print subelements of customer_domains var:

```
- name: print customer_domains SUBELEMENTS
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ scx_customer_domains }}"
    - sender_domains
```

Answer (score 0):

why not this ?

```
- name: assert unique sender_domains
  assert:
    that: item.sender_domains == item.sender_domains|uniq
  loop: '{{ customer_domains }}'
  when: '"sender_domains" in item'
```

And in case you want to make sure sender_domains are globally unique, you can

```
vars:
  all_sender_domains: '{{ customer_domains | map(attribute="sender_domains") | list | select("defined") | list | flatten }}'

tasks:
- assert:
    that:
      - all_sender_domains == all_sender_domains | uniq
```

Comment: That works. What if we want it to assert dups in *all* sender_domains list, regardless of *name* lists that they belong to?